# how to configure jetty 7 to use syslog or log4j

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, jetty, syslog

I am looking for a way to direct all the jetty 7 logging to syslog. My current configuration 
dumps everything to JETTY_HOME/logs/.. After some initial ivestigation, it seems I should change JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty-logging.xml, but this does not look straightforward. It looks like I should create a new PrintStream implementation which sends its output to syslog and redirecting stderr and stdout to that class in jetty-logging.xml.

any easier way to do that or to make jetty log directly to log4j ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this advice by David Yu](http://communitymapbuilder.org/display/JETTY/Server+Log), it should be as simple as making org.slf4j.Logger available, which didn't work for me. However, in unix you could do something like

```
java ... -Djetty.home=/usr/share/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp \
  -jar /usr/share/jetty/start.jar /usr/share/jetty/etc/jetty.xml 2>&1 |
  logger -t jetty
```

In etc/jetty.xml, you may also want to comment out the line that calls RequestLogImpl.setFilename.